# How can I get all google business which is registered on google by search its name using API?

Tags: google-my-business-api

I need help related API. First of all, I want to know that Google provides any kind of API that gives the search result of all google business which is registered on google using the business name and its address.

If yes then it's good for me and please give me any link of documentation.

I have also checked google documentation of google API. But I can not found the exact API that I need.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/

Answer (score 0):

GMB has api `googleLocations.search`, we can search by location object or query string. Hope this will help.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/googleLocations/search

We can also use `locations.fineMatches` API for unverified locations

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/findMatches

Comment: Do yoy know that we can get all review s of unverified business using the GBM?

Comment: @BhavinThummar I don't this you get reviews for unverified location. See [this](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list) for more info. From docs `This operation is only valid if the specified location is verified.`